# ORA-00903 : invalid table name when make trigger after insert Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvOkX.jpg)

I'm trying to create trigger :

```
Create or Replace trigger poin_member
After Insert on dtl_poin
For Each Row
Begin
Update into tb_member set total_poin = total_poin + NEW.tambahan poin
Where id_member=NEW.id_member;
End;
```

To add up every data insert on `tambahan_poin` that have the same `id_member` and insert the sum results into `total_poin` but error invalid table name. even though the table name entered is correct.
what's the solution?

Comment: `:new` instead of `new`? It would help, if you told us to which token the error refers, i.e. post the whole error message, verbatim.

Comment: yes, you can see the attached image to see the error message

Comment: Do not post images of error messages (or code). Paste the **text** into the question.

Comment: And have you tried to use `:new` instead of `new`?

Comment: Error messages: sql statement ignored and ora-00903-invalid table name

Comment: yes i have tried it

Answer (score 1):

Oracle points you to error position. It says:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------  -------------------------------------
2/1       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/8       PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

Line #2:

```
Update into tb_member 
--------
12345678
       ^
       |
     error is here. Obviously, invalid syntax. You can't use INTO here
```

So, yes - you should pay attention to what Oracle says and do *something* about it.

---

Quite a few errors. I'm creating sample tables, just to make trigger compile. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE dtl_poin
  2  (
  3     id_member       NUMBER,
  4     tambahan_poin   NUMBER --> in your trigger, you used "NEW.tambahan poin" which is invalid
  5                            --  as there can't be any space in column name (unless enclosed
  6                            --  into double quotes)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE tb_member
  2  (
  3     id_member    NUMBER,
  4     total_poin   NUMBER
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER poin_member
  2     AFTER INSERT
  3     ON dtl_poin
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     -- UPDATE INTO tb_member            --> wrong syntax; INTO can't be used here
  7     UPDATE tb_member
  8        SET total_poin = total_poin + :NEW.tambahan_poin
  9      WHERE id_member = :NEW.id_member;
 10  END;
 11  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO tb_member (id_member, total_poin)
  2       VALUES (1, 25);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO dtl_poin (id_member, tambahan_poin)
  2       VALUES (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM dtl_poin;

 ID_MEMBER TAMBAHAN_POIN
---------- -------------
         1           100

SQL> SELECT * FROM tb_member;

 ID_MEMBER TOTAL_POIN
---------- ----------
         1        125        --> good; 100 was added to 25 and the result is now 125

SQL>
```

Comment: May be. You never posted **tables' description** so I had to create my own test case. As demonstrated, code *works* on **my** tables. If it doesn't on yours, adjust it so that it works. I have no idea which columns your tables really have.